# removing spaces from integer column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using a number column in my dataframe for a simple lookup, however one of the record has spaces and it botched the lookup. Below is just a sample column from the actual file.

```
Column
90043
216977   
98207
```

record two `216977` is the one followed by 3 white spaces. I tried using `strip()` and `apply(lambda x: x.strip())`, but unfortunately they don't work on numeric columns. Can anyone pls suggest what am I doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should show more of your code : how do you read the file?

Comment: have you tried [to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) method?

Comment: `df.Column = df.Column.str.replace(' ','').astype(int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of the fields has a space, chances are it's a number stored as a string. You can try to cast the type as int.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1],['2 '],[3]], columns=['Messy Data'])

df

  Messy Data
0          1
1         2 
2          3
```

Now use apply & lambda to cast everything to an int

```
df['Messy Data'] = df['Messy Data'].apply(lambda x: int(x))

df
   Messy Data
0           1
1           2
2           3
```

Comment: thanks...this was exactly what was the case...a number stored as string..thank you :)